# If Else statement when there are more than two parameters

Tags: php, if-statement

I've a table name with 3 and 4 fields and I'm gonna use if statement for these  tables. currently this following code is working well when there are only **two parameters** but if its more than two I don't know how to use it.

```
if ($history->getPsychological()) {
    if($history->getPsychological() == 'Polymenore'){
        $psychological = "Polymenore";
        echo "<img height=\"30\" src=\"images/polymenorrhea.png\" width=\"250\" />\n";
    } else {
        $psychological = "Oligomenore";
        echo "<img height=\"30\" src=\"images/oligomenorrhea.png\" width=\"250\" />\n";
    }
}
```

**In above code, if psychological is Polymenore then it will show its image, else it will show Oligomenore.**

I mean, its two fields, 1: Polymenore  2: Oligomenore and it's working well.

so, here is my question,

If  there are  more than two fields, I mean like 3 and 4 fields, how can I use it into above code:

For example:

> How to use it with 3 fields
>
> **psychological  with  1: A  2: B  3: C**
>
> and How to use it with 4 fields
>
> **psychological  with  1: A  2: B  3: C  4: D**

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Where is JAVA in this question?

Comment: You're looking for `else if`, or `elseif`, or `switch`? Or even a table with index/value? Did you read the "control structure" of PHP documentation?

Comment: Use [else if](http://php.net/manual/bg/control-structures.elseif.php) or [switch-case](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[You're looking for `elseif/else if`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.elseif.php)**.

Syntax:

```
if($foo){
    //what happens if $foo is true
} elseif($bar){
    //what happens if $foo is false and $bar is true
} elseif(...){
    //any other checks ad infinitum
} else {
    //what happens if no other case is true
}
```

Your example:

```
if ($history->getPsychological()) {
    if($history->getPsychological() == 'Polymenore'){
        $psychological = "Polymenore";
        echo "<img height=\"30\" src=\"images/polymenorrhea.png\" width=\"250\" />\n";
    } elseif($history->getPsychological() == 'Oligomenore') {
        $psychological = "Oligomenore";
        echo "<img height=\"30\" src=\"images/oligomenorrhea.png\" width=\"250\" />\n";
    } elseif(....){
        //...
    } else {
        //...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much .. :-)

Answer (score 1):

use multiple ifs:

```
if ($history->getPsychological()) {
    if($history->getPsychological() == 'Polymenore'){
        ...
    } 
    if($history->getPsychological() == 'other1')
        ...
    }
    if($history->getPsychological() == 'other2')
        ...
    }
    //$psychological = "Oligomenore";
    echo "<img height=\"30\" src=\"images/oligomenorrhea.png\" width=\"250\"/>\n";
}
```

or switch:

```
switch (month) {
            case 1:  $history->getPsychological() == "'Polymenore'";
                     ...
            case 2:  $history->getPsychological() == "other1";
                     ...;
            case 3:  $history->getPsychological() == "March";
                     ...;
            default:...
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 if ($history->getPsychological()) {

    swtich( $history->getPsychological() )
    {
        case 'Polymenore':
        {
            $psychological = "Polymenore";
            echo "<img height=\"30\" src=\"images/polymenorrhea.png\" width=\"250\" />\n";
            break;
        }

        case 'Oligomenore':
        {
            $psychological = "Oligomenore";
            echo "<img height=\"30\" src=\"images/oligomenorrhea.png\" width=\"250\" />\n";
            break;
        }

        case '3':
        {
            ....
            break;
        }
    }

}
```